# "Method Name Expected" error C# when using invoke

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, delegates, task

I am trying to get a thread to return info to "JobViews" in a Win Forms Application. But when calling an invoke I'm getting a "Method Name Expected" error.

Here's my current code,

```
    public void initJobListViews_DoWork(string IP, int Port)
    {
        initJobListViews();
        bool JobString = fillJobViews(IP, Port);
    }

    public void SocketClientReturn(string IP, int Port)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new SocketClientReturnDelegate(initJobListViews_DoWork(IP, Port)));
/// this.Invoke(new SocketClientReturnDelegate(initJobListViews_DoWork(IP, Port),null));
// Also complains 
        }
        else
        {
            initJobListViews_DoWork(IP, Port);
        }
    }

private delegate void SocketClientReturnDelegate();
```

I have also tried the following,

```
    public void initJobListViews_DoWork(string IP, int Port)
    {
        initJobListViews();
        bool JobString = fillJobViews(IP, Port);
    }

    public void SocketClientReturn(string IP, int Port)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new SocketClientReturnDelegate(initJobListViews_DoWork));
        }
        else
        {
            initJobListViews_DoWork(IP, Port);
        }
    }

private delegate void SocketClientReturnDelegate(string IP, int Port);
```

This results in no issues during compile, but the program throws a "TargetParameterCountException" whilst running.

I've used this technique before without issue, and I'm a little stumped as to why its failing this time??

Comment: You're trying to call the function; `Invoke` expects a delegate, i.e., just pass the function identifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Invoke` is expecting the delegate and you are calling the function do this instead,

```
 this.Invoke(new SocketClientReturnDelegate(initJobListViews_DoWork),new object[]{IP, Port});
```

Comment: Thanks (both replies), that makes sense now (and the problems now solved) :).